# Images not loading for lastpass in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, lastpass

In my Google Chrome. I have the lastpass plugin installed but it does not load the images. You can see this in action in this screen recording: http://youtu.be/RllVrSiPKvM